# Mountain Lion desktop order

Tags: macos, spaces, desktop

On Mountain Lion, I have three desktops. What I find is that the sequential left to right order of these desktops keeps changing. Is it doing something based on usage ? and how can I disable this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable it in System Preferences:

[image]